# Converting daily transaction data to the sum of the end of each week

Tags: r

I have daily transaction data that I want to convert into a weekly sum (i.e. the sum of transactions each week for the week ending Sunday).

It is currently structured like this

```
dataset <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("20200407", "20200407", "20200407", "20200407"), "%Y%m%d"), category=c("Petrol Station", "Accomodation", "Discount Store", "Shopping"), amount=c(5431.47, 839.1, 2399.13, 1305.82))
```

- Date - essentially is all the different transactions on that day(I've already reformatted using the ydm function)
- Category - the different types of spending
- amount - is the spend.

  ```
  date        category        amount
  2020-04-07  Petrol Station  5431.47
  2020-04-07  Accommodation   839.1
  2020-04-07  Discount Store  2399.13
  2020-04-07  Shopping        1305.82
  ```

In total, there's about 100k lines over 3 years of data

I am able to create a week variable using the below (which gives me W1, W2, ...,etc.) and sum it by grouping it. However, it doesn't seem to work properly in Week 1 and Week 52 where there isn't a full 7 days

```
dataset$Week <- strftime(dataset$date, format = "%Y-W%V")
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TobKei's contribution is great you just need to change a bit the structure of your dataset to achieve what you need. Essentially, you need to have each category's values as a variable to be able to generate a weekly sum without it being one single number. You may want to try the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

sum_output <- dataset %>%
  mutate(week = week(date)) %>%
  spread(., category, amount) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarise(accomodation_week_sum = sum(Accomodation), 
         discount_store_week_sum= sum(`Discount Store`), 
         Petrol_week_sum=sum(`Petrol Station`), 
         shopping_week_sum= sum(Shopping))
```

For the moment it's the same number since you don't have more observations from the same week but eventually if you had more the `group_by()` would return you one sum per week.

***UPDATE***: The following should work in case you have hundreds of categories that you obviously don't want to be typing individually:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

sum_output <- dataset %>%
  mutate(week = week(date)) %>%
  split(.$category) %>%
  lapply(., group_by, week) %>%
  lapply(., summarise, week_sum_amount=sum(amount)) %>%
  bind_rows(., .id = "week_sum_amount") %>% 
  data.frame(check.names = FALSE)
```

The main addition is the `split()` which will separate all your categories in different dataframes within one list. A list of dataframes.

Comment: Cool - that looks good.

There is around 400 sub categories though, is there a simple way to transform them?

Comment: Thanks @yach 

It seems to have put me closer, but it puts out around 400 datafames, each with one row and one column (correctly adding up the overall total).

I suspect I need to have a  different group function by week in it?

Comment: For the current form of your dataset you don't need another group_by. It returns 2 columns and as many rows as the weeks. Take the following dataset as an example:

Comment: ```dataset <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c("20200407", "20200407", "20200407", "20200407", "20200406", "20200406", "20200406", "20200408", "20200408", "20200408", "20200408", "20200408"), "%Y%m%d"), category=c("Petrol Station", "Accomodation", "Discount Store", "Shopping", "Petrol Station", "Accomodation", "Discount Store", "Shopping", "Petrol Station", "Accomodation", "Discount Store", "Shopping"), amount=c(5431.47, 839.1, 2399.13, 1305.82, 2000, 1800, 3500, 1670, 1500, 1400, 2900, 2000))```


It's just like your initial one but I have added more observations by two weeks.

Comment: If in my proposed solution you add: ```sum_output <- sum_output %>% bind_rows(., id="week_sum_amount") %>% data.frame( check.names=FALSE)``` Then it will merge again all 400 dataframes in one. You choose what is more convenient for your process.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dataset%>%
  mutate(week = week(date))%>%
  group_by(week)%>%
  summarize(week_sum = sum(amount))
```

If you want to get an etxtra "category"-evaluation than:

```
dataset%>%
  mutate(week = week(date))%>%
  group_by(week, category)%>%
  summarize(week_category_sum = sum(amount))
```

EDIT:

@TobKel Something like this - but for each individual subcategory in the category column (there is around 100).

I can generate the below fine, its just the Week 01 and Week 52 that don't have a full seven days in them

[image: output]

Comment: That seems to give me a single output.

Ideally I am wanting to get a weekly sum (7 day sum to Sunday) for each sub category over the 2 years.

I.e. for each sub-category I would have 52 weeks of week data that sums the 7 days to Sunday.

Comment: Then what you need to do is some data wrangling beforehand. For example:

 ```dataset %>%
  mutate(week = week(date)) %>%
  spread(., category, amount)```

Comment: @Josh can you give as an example of your desired output?

Comment: @TobKel Something like this - but for each individual subcategory in the category column (there is around 100).

I can generate the below fine, its just the Week 01 and Week 52 that don't have a full seven days in them

Week category amount
2018-W01 Food/Drink >> Fast Food 9091946.07
2018-W02 Food/Drink >> Fast Food 8242358.22
2018-W03 Food/Drink >> Fast Food 8609234.22
2018-W04 Food/Drink >> Fast Food 8340712.86
2018-W05 Food/Drink >> Fast Food 8084297.38
2018-W06 Food/Drink >> Fast Food 8235502.35
2018-W07 Food/Drink >> Fast Food 8373676.62

Answer (score 1):

With your example using the data.table and lubridate packages:

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
# convert data.frame to data.table
setDT(dataset)
# add week variable, then sum grouping by week and category 
dataset[, week := week(date)][, 
  wkSum = sum(amount), keyby = c("week", "category")]
```

Modifying your example data a little to cover multiple weeks and repeats of categories to show that it works, this input

```
         date       category  amount
1: 2020-04-06       Shopping 1203.54
2: 2020-04-07 Petrol Station 5431.47
3: 2020-04-07       Shopping 1305.82
4: 2020-04-08       Shopping 1400.43
```

Gives the output

```
   week       category   wkSum
1:   14 Petrol Station 5431.47
2:   14       Shopping 2509.36
3:   15       Shopping 1400.43
```